# Server redirect requests

Tags: linux, nginx, apache2

First, I'm trying make an main-server with my database and my files, and create 1 small servers to redirect requests, for example:

[SMALL-SERVER] IP: 1.1.1.1
[MASTER-SERVER] IP: 9.9.9.9
My website: server.com

**server.com** will point to **1.1.1.1** (*small-server*), and this small server will forward all requests to **9.9.9.9** (*master-server*), but I don't want the domain be changed, the small server will only redirect all requests to *master-server*

e.g.: http://server.com => *small-server* will throw the user to master-server

Using nginx or apache, how can I do that? (LINUX)

Thank you very much.